# Rigorous workthrough of why cone is not a submanifold on $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, submanifold

I know there are a couple of questions on this, but they don't have a fully worked out answer and I'm still trying to wrap my mind around submanifolds so I don't really get what exactly I need to do.

Here is the question:

**Prove that the $M=\{(x,y,z)|x^2+y^2-z^2=0 \quad and\quad z\geq0)\}\in\mathbb{R}^3$ is not a $C^1$-submanifold on $\mathbb{R}^3$**

Attempt at solution:

For $M$ to be a $k$-dimensional submanifold, we need that for every point in $M$, and therefore also for $(0,0,0)$, there exists an neighborhood $W$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and a $C^1$-map $F:W\to\mathbb{R}^{3-k}$ such that

1. $\text{rank } dF_r = n-k\quad r\in M\cap W$
2. $M\cap W = F^{-1}(0)\cap W$

So the problem is that the rank of the tangent space at the vertex is always going to be $n$, in this case $3$, thus violating the 1st condition. But how do I write this down as a rigorous answer?

Comment: I think it would go something like:  (1) Find three "tangent vectors to M" at the origin that give a basis for $R^3$. (2) Show that under your two conditions, $dF$ must take any vector tangent to $M$ to 0.  (3) Find a contradiction between these two findings by showing that they imply the rank of dF must be 0 at the origin.

Comment: You can reduce the problem to an easier one with the following argument. If it where a submanifold, the tangent plane at the origine must be tranvserse to another plane, containing the vertical (either $x=0$ or $y=0$) . Its intersection with such a plane is the graph of the function $z= \vert x \vert$, which is not a smooth curve as there is no tangent vector to the origin.